# How to make continuously running TransitionDrawable animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, drawable, transition

I'm trying to make an animated logo. It consists of two static images.

I would to like to achieve a cross-fading effect.

I've done it with the use of TransitionDrawable, set the crossFadeEnabled and everything looks nice.

The thing is that I need to be running in circle. How can it be achieved ?

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_expand">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_collapse">
</transition>

Resources res = mContext.getResources();
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.expand_collapse);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toggle_image);
image.setImageDrawable(transition);
```

This the code from google which runs perfectly.
The most importantn thing is that in needs to work under Android 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the transition drawable to work via a handler method that reverses direction after the transition from drawable1 to drawable2. In my XML's :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_animation1"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_animation2"/>

</transition>
```

The drawables are gradients :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
     <corners android:topLeftRadius = "10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#d200ff" 
        android:centerColor="#4e00ff"
        android:endColor="#006cff"/>

</shape>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size android:width="900dp" android:height="500dp"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius = "10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#006cff" 
        android:centerColor="#ff6600"
        android:endColor="#d200ff"/>

</shape>
```

In my initialisation code :

```html
trans = (TransitionDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transition);
  trans.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
  backgroundimage.setImageDrawable(trans);

....

handlechange();
```

And the most important bit in the handler code; note the flag that is running globally. I got this running on Gingerbread and Kitkat;

```html
void handlechange1()
 {
  Handler hand = new Handler();
  hand.postDelayed(new Runnable()
  {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    change();
   }
   private void change()
   {
    if (flag)
    {
     trans.startTransition(8000);
     flag = false;
    } else
    {
     trans.reverseTransition(8000);
     flag = true;
    }
    handlechange1();
   }
  }, 8000);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a built-in way to do this.  `TransitionDrawable` is not designed with an infinite looping animation function.  The easiest recommendation would be to use an `Animation` (alpha, scale, translate, etc.) on a `View` containing just one of your `Drawable`s if you can.

A fairly easy hack would be to add a `Handler` and callback to your custom `View` holding your `TransitionDrawable`.  When the `View` is created, the `Handler` can be set to your transition interval.  The `View` would also implement `Handler.Callback` and inside its `handleMessage(Message)` method, it would call `reverseTransition(int)` on your `TransitionDrawable`.

A rough example is below:

```
public class myView extends View implements Handler.Callback {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(this);

    private int mDelay = 1000; // Delay in milliseconds.

    private Runnable mEvent = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mEvent);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mEvent, mDelay);
            Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    };

    public View(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Set your background TransitionDrawable.
        setBackgroundDrawable(...);
    }

    public handleMessage(Message message) {
        TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) getBackgroundDrawable();
        drawable.reverseTransition(mDelay);
    }

    public void start() {
        mHandler.post(mEvent);
    }

    public void stop() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mEvent);
    }

}
```

Call `start()` to start your continuous transition, `stop()` to stop it.  It is a bit like creating your own animation, but it works in a pinch.